# Regular expressions: obtain substring between two slashes?

Tags: c#, regex

Given the string

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.php
```

…I want to obtain the substring between the 3rd slash `(.*?)` and last slash, i.e.:

```
questions/ask
```

How can I accomplish this with regular expressions in C#?

Comment: Maybe look at [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.php");
string s = string.Join("", url.Segments.Take(url.Segments.Length - 1)).Trim('/');
```

Comment: This will have an extra `/` at the beginning, but looks good.

Comment: You have to `.Trim('/')` to get exactly what OP requires.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [`Uri.Segments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx) Property

```
Uri uriAddress1 = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/title/index.htm");
Console.WriteLine("The parts are {0}, {1}, {2}", uriAddress1.Segments[0], 
   uriAddress1.Segments[1], uriAddress1.Segments[2]);
```

Produces the following output:

```
The parts are /, title/, index.htm
```

Comment: +1 for Segments, to completely match the question one would need to remove first and last segments instead of hard-coding 1 and 2 (i.e. "http://www.contoso.com/title/foo/bar/index.htm" according to question should yield "title/foo/bar" which is 3 segments)

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.php");
string result = uri.Segments[1] + uri.Segments[2];
result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use existing Uri and Path classes instead of string matching and regular expressions. Something like:

```
 Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(url).AbsolutePath)
```

Comment: @lnnahdbandninja Now you have two problems.

Comment: @lnnahdbandninja, it is not very good idea to roll out your own custom parsing of Urls if there is existing tested code for that - answers with Segments are much safer than you  get with regular expressions alone...

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be using the Uri object.

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.php");
string[] s = u.Segments;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are the way to go. But if you are still looking for the regex this one should work:

```
([^/]*/[^/]*)/[^/]*$
```

The path you are looking for is in the first submatch.